# How to view data based on date range using laravel and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, date

Route:

```
Route::post('dategraph','Chatbot\TrackerController@dategraph');
```

Controller:

```
public function dategraph(Request $request)
{
    $dategraph = DiraStatistics::all()->whereBetween('date_access', [$from, $to])->get();

    $dates = $dategraph('date_access');

    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('dates'));
}
```

View:

```
<form id="form-project" role="form" action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\TrackerController@dategraph')}}" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

          {{csrf_field()}}
          <!-- <canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="50"></canvas> -->

            <div class="form-group-attached">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group form-group-default required" >
                          <label>From</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group form-group-default required" >
                          <label>To</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn alt-btn-black btn-xs alt-btn pull-right" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Hi guys, so im trying to view the data from the selected dates as the code ive written. But im getting an error. Did i write it correctly? or am i missing something?

Comment: `[$from, $to]` can't see the values of these in the code.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo sorry what do you mean?

Comment: values of $from and $to, you need to get them from $request as  `$request->input()['from']`

Comment: also you are using both `all()` and `get()`?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you post the errors too ?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo i added 

    $request->input()['from'];
    $request->input()['to'];

it still doesnt work.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai currently im getting : Undefined variable: from

Comment: @IJas currently im getting : Undefined variable:

Comment: Please update ur question with the error. It makes easier to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a `$from` variable.
You need to pull out posted variables from the request.

The method `get()` will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) of objects. You can, for example, turn it to a flat array by plucking the column and turning it `toArray()`

```
$dategraph = DiraStatistics::whereBetween(
    'date_access', 
    [
        $request->get('from'),
        $request->get('to')
    ]
)->get();
$dates = $dategraph->pluck('date_access')->toArray();
```